HTML Content is not recognized in mail utility
I need to get a mail with HTML Structured and attachment with it but the below code is resulting only mail with HTML Script
#!/bin/bash
set -x  # Enable debugging output
set +x  # Disable debugging output
AWK=/bin/awk
CAT=/bin/cat
RM=/bin/rm
MAIL=/bin/mail
MKTEMP=/bin/mktemp
# Function to convert CSV to HTML table

csv_to_html_table() {
${AWK} -F',' 'BEGIN{print "\<table style="font-size: 13" border="1" cellspacing="0"    cellpadding="2"\>" }
{
if (NR == 1) {
print "\<tr\>";
for(i=1; i\<=NF; i++)
print "\<td\><b>" toupper($i) "</b>\</td\>";
print "\</tr\>";
} else {
print "\<tr\>";
for(i=1; i\<=NF; i++)
print "\<td\>" $i "\</td\>";
print "\</tr\>";
}
}
END{print "\</table\>"}' "$1"
}

mail_sub=$1
csv_file=$2

# CSV file path

ERROR_FILE=abc.csv

html_table=$(csv_to_html_table "$csv_file")

# Define email details

EMAIL_TO="abc@domain.com"
EMAIL_SUBJECT=$mail_sub`your text`
PROXY_EMAILID="cdf@domain.com"
MSG_FILE=$($MKTEMP)

Create the email body with correct MIME headers for HTML content
{
echo "From: $PROXY_EMAILID"
echo "To: $EMAIL_TO"
echo "Subject: $EMAIL_SUBJECT"
echo "Mime-Version: 1.0"
echo "Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8""
echo
echo "\<html\>\<body\><p>Hi Team,<br><p>Please find the $mail_sub and its Count<br>${html_table}<br>(Note:  This is an automated message and does not require a response.)<br><p>Regards,<p>Team\</body\>\</html\>"
} \> "$MSG_FILE"

# Debug: Print email message file content

echo "Email Message File Content:"
$CAT "$MSG_FILE"

# Send email using mail command with attachment

$MAIL -a "$ERROR_FILE" -s "$EMAIL_SUBJECT" -r "$PROXY_EMAILID" "$EMAIL_TO" \< "$MSG_FILE"
`your text`

# Cleanup temporary file

$RM "$MSG_FILE"

